# Make /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct persistent

Tags: startup, intel, overheating

Is it possible to make the value of /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct persistent? Is there a kernel parameter? I have to do this to prevent overheating…

I currently set it every time manually after startup using echo 85 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct but the value is reset every time I restart the machine.

Comment: No. You will have to make something to automatically run at startup to do what you want. For overheating, yes it is a good idea to find the max_perf_pct where overheat does not occur, just for information purposes. Then it would be a good idea to use a thermal monitoring daemon, such as thermald, to control maximum CPU frequency automatically, thereby not universally limiting the upper bound (i.e. when only 1 core is active, it is probably O.K. to go to higher CPU frequency).

Comment: Hmm, okay, thank you.  
Is it worth having a separate thermal daemon for this or can I rely on the daemon (whichever this is?) that already generates these logs:  

`[ 3863.970201] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 375)`  

```[ 3863.975203] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal```?

Comment: Those messages are directly from the kernel itself. Normally you would not want those (almost) final levels of defence to be hit in the first place. Yes, a properly operating thermal daemon, such as thermald, should take action before the kernel itself has to step in. as a starting point, try it with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You may create `oneshot` service that would set it for you.

1. Create service

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/intel_pstate_setup.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Set maximum performance to 75% and min performance to 30%

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 75 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct; echo 30 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Enable
   `sudo systemctl enable intel_pstate_setup`
3. Reboot
   Now when you check you should see:

```sh
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct 
75
```